# WYSIWYG editor with image drop-n-drop feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, editor

Where can I get a WYSIWYG editor like the one used in github.com? I can drop-n-drop images on the editor while posting a message. Gmail composer in Chrome has a similar function.

Bye the way, I am a rails developer. So rails gem would be plus.

Answer (score 1):

[SammyLin / redactor-rails](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails) gem can do this for you, in conjunction with an upload gem such as carrierwave (all explained in the documentation).